# Обработать Infinity при делении на ноль java

Tags: java

Подскажите где ошибка? Не получается обработать деление на ноль.

```
     public class Calculator_OOP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculatorLogic calclogic = new CalculatorLogic();
        Calculator calc = new Calculator(calclogic);
        calc.exec();
    }
}
interface Operation {
    double exec(double first_value, double second_value);
}

class Addition implements Operation {
    public double exec(double first_value, double second_value) {
        return (first_value + second_value);
    }
}

class Subtraction implements Operation {
    public double exec(double first_value, double second_value) {
        return (first_value - second_value);
    }
}

class Multiply implements Operation {
    public double exec(double first_value, double second_value) {
        return (first_value * second_value);
    }
}

class Division implements Operation {
    public double exec(double first_value, double second_value) {
 if (second_value==0) {
     throw new DivisionByZero();
 }
        return (first_value / second_value);
    }
}
interface Operations {
    Operation getOper(char op);
}
class CalculatorLogic implements Operations {
    char resOperation;
    public Operation operation;
    public Operation getOper(char op) {
            this.resOperation = op;
            switch (resOperation) {
                case '+': {
                    operation = new Addition();
                    break;
                }
                case '-': {
                    operation = new Subtraction();
                    break;
                }
                case '*': {
                    operation = new Multiply();
                    break;
                }
                case '/': {
                    operation = new Division();
                    break;
                }
                default:
            }
        return operation;
    }
}
class Calculator {
    CalculatorLogic resultOperation;
    public Calculator(CalculatorLogic resultOperation) {
        this.resultOperation = resultOperation;
    }

    public void exec() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        try {
            System.out.println("Введите первое число и нажмите Enter");
            double num1 = scanner.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Выберите операцию: +, -, *, / и нажмите Enter");
            char operation = scanner.next().trim().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("Введите второе число и нажмите Enter");
            double num2 = scanner.nextDouble();
            Operation op = resultOperation.getOper(operation);
            if (op != null) System.out.println("Ответ: " + op.exec(num1, num2));
            else System.out.println("Error: Не верная операция!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка: Не верное значение!");
        }
    }
    public class DivisionByZero extends Exception {}
```

Comment: Приведите трассировку ошибки, которая у Вас возникает, а также входные данные. Судя по Вашему коду, Вы генерируете exception, когда делитель = 0 и это правильно, так что же именно нужно сделать?

Comment: При делении на ноль хочу, чтобы выводилось сообщение "Делить на ноль нельзя"Error:(51, 16) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class DivisionByZero
  location: class Project_Calculator_OOP.Division

Comment: где у Вас код класса DivisionByZero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Проблема в том, что Вы в своем старом коде не обрабатывали генерируемое исключение DivisionByZero(кстати, лучше класс исключений называть DivisionByZeroException, чтобы не отходить от именных конвенций). А то что Вы написали в комментарии - означает что компилятор не видит этот класс DivisionByZero, где его код? Можете не писать свой класс, а использовать ArithmeticException, тогда

```
     class Division implements Operation {
       public double exec(double first_value, double second_value) {
         if (second_value==0) {
           throw new ArithmeticException("На ноль делить нельзя");
         }
         return (first_value / second_value);
        }
      }





   try {
        System.out.println("Введите первое число и нажмите Enter");
        double num1 = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Выберите операцию: +, -, *, / и нажмите Enter");
        char operation = scanner.next().trim().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Введите второе число и нажмите Enter");
        double num2 = scanner.nextDouble();
        Operation op = resultOperation.getOper(operation);
        try {
          if (op != null) System.out.println("Ответ: " + op.exec(num1, num2));
          else System.out.println("Error: Не верная операция!");
        } catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка: Не верное значение!");
    }
```

Comment: То есть если выдает такую ошибку то нормально?
java.lang.ArithmeticException: На ноль делить нельзя
 at Project_Calculator_OOP.Division.exec(Calculator_OOP.java:51)
 at Project_Calculator_OOP.Calculator.exec(Calculator_OOP.java:118)
 at Project_Calculator_OOP.Calculator_OOP.main(Calculator_OOP.java:20)

Comment: @AlexLip да, конечно, если Вас пугает красный цвет логера исключений - то можете ex.printStackTrace() заменить на System.out.println(ex.getMessage()) и тогда на экран просто выведет "На ноль делить нельзя".

Comment: Спасибо! Да, разобрался уже)